# Palindrome check with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I was learning about recursion and was attempting a palindrome check. It is not working. Can someone help me figure out the reason.

```
private static bool CheckPalin(string p)
{
    if(p.Length == 1 || p.Length == 0)  //added check for even cases
        return true;
    if(p[0] != p[p.Length -1])
        return false;

    CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Which test inputs work? Which test inputs fail? What happens if you're passed `aa` as an input?

Comment: Add a line to print out "p" each time it goes through the loop, or manually set a break point and step through each loop

Comment: No it is not. I was trying to learn. Thats the reason I did not google the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dan hit one failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675008/377270) square on the head (as implied by my question about `aa` -- length `0` strings will give you trouble).

The other failure case, as indicated by *false positives* is actually pretty obvious once you take a quick step back and look for it:

```
CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2));
return true;
```

Try:

```
return CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2));
```

It's amazing, I skimmed it twice without noticing it -- until you pointed out the false positives. :)

Comment: thanks, I missed a termination condition and the very idea of recursion. :(

Comment: It definitely takes a few tries before it makes sense. :)

Comment: I am not very sure about the unwinding part. Suppose I have a string "irbeyuibri". When it checks 'e' != 'i' it returns false. What exactly happens after that? When I traced through the code, it keep on hitting CheckPalin call with "beyuib", "rbeyuibr" and "irbeyuibri".

Comment: Step back one more step, and you'll find that the `false` propagates all the way back up to the original call: `bool palin = CheckPalin("irbeyuibri");` -- `palin` will also be `false`.

Comment: ok, looks like I am getting it. thanks a lot! ah, infact, it is not calling again, just returning the values of previous calls.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if `p.Length == 0`?

Your code probably returns false or crashes, whereas it should return true. Or alternately, return true when `p.Length == 2` just before calling `CheckPalin` and just after confirming that `p[0] == p[p.Length -1]`.

Also you don't understand how recursion works. Your last line should be

```
return CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2));
```

Comment: Missed it. Thanks for pointing out. I sure don't know recursion yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2)); 
return true;
```

to:

```
return CheckPalin(p.SubsString(1, p.Length -2));
```