# c# console application program for palindrome string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public static int isPalindrome(char[] String)
{
     if (String.Length == 0 || String.Length == 1)
         return 1;
     if (String[0] != String[String.Length - 1])
         return 0;
     return Convert.ToUInt32(isPalindrome(String);
}
```

I am not able to make it as instance method i am getting problems so please help me how to make it as dynamic

Comment: i want this is for recursive function

Comment: i tried for recursive function but input parameter as string not char[]

public static int isPalindrome(string p)
        {
            if (p.Length == 1 || p.Length == 0)
                return 1;
            if (p[0] != p[p.Length - 1])
                return 0;
            return isPalindrome(p.Substring(1, p.Length - 2));
        }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Palindrome check with recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674997/palindrome-check-with-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    public static int isPalindrome(char[] String)
    {
        string smallerString = String.ToString().Substring(1, String.Length - 1);
        if (String.Length == 0 || String.Length == 1)
             return 1;
         if (String[0] != String[String.Length - 1])
             return 0;

         return Convert.ToInt32(isPalindrome(smallerString.ToCharArray()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your types and return values

```
public static int isPalindrome(char[] str)
{
    if (str.Length == 0 || str.Length == 1)
        return 1;
    if (str[0] != str[str.Length - 1])
        return 0;
    return isPalindrome(str.Skip(1).Take(str.Length-2).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: how to make this same function as dynamic in the sense INSTANCE method
i want to take input from user then how? and how to call it in main method also

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the same value to isPalindrome again and again. You can try something like the following (note I've used string in the example below):

```
private static bool isPalindrome(string s)
{
    if(s.Length == 1 || s.Length == 0)
        return true;
    if(s[0] != s[s.Length -1])
        return false;

    return isPalindrome(s.SubsString(1, s.Length -2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be very easy implemented.

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(String text)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
           return false;

    char[] arr = text.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    var reversedText = new string(arr);         
    return string.Equals(text, reversedText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```